# Intellij cannot resolve method even though it is public (Java)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, polymorphism, constraints, visibility

I have googled this a lot, invalidated the cache, and I can't seem to find an answer. For background, this is a timetabling system using constraint solving. I have a custom class called `Period` with public methods `getStart()` and `getEnd()`. I also have an abstract class `Constraint<V, D>` and a subclass `DemAvailConstratint<Demonstrator, Period>`. It is in this subclass (and similarly in another one) where the methods in `Period` and `Demonstrator` cannot be resolved.

In `DemAvailConstraint` the methods showing the error are `getStart()` and `getEnd()` when called on `this.period` but not when called on other `Period` objects. Similarly, it happens with `isAvailable()` when called on `this.getDemonstrator()` in the `satisfied()` method. This is a public method in `Demonstrator`. Any idea why this would happen?

Here are the classes (with some methods removed for clarity):

```
public abstract class Constraint<V, D> {
    private V variable;
    
    public Constraint(V variable) {
        this.variable = variable;
    }
    
    public abstract boolean satisfied();
    
    public abstract int score();
    
    protected V getVariable() {
        return this.variable;
    }
    
    protected void setVariable(V variable) {
        this.variable = variable;
    }
}
```

```
public class DemAvailConstraint<Demonstrator, Period> extends Constraint {
    private Period period;
    private ArrayList<AvailBlock> periodAsBlocks;
    
    public DemAvailConstraint(Demonstrator demonstrator, Period period) {
        super(demonstrator);
        this.period = period;
        periodAsBlocks = new ArrayList<>();
        periodAsBlocks.add( AvailBlock.from(this.period.getStart()) );
        while ( periodAsBlocks.get( periodAsBlocks.size() - 1 ).getEnd().isBefore(this.period.getEnd()) ) {
            periodAsBlocks.add( AvailBlock.from(periodAsBlocks.get( periodAsBlocks.size() - 1 ).getEnd()) );
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean satisfied() {
        // now we check if the demonstrator is available for each block
        for (AvailBlock block : this.periodAsBlocks) {
            if ( !this.getDemonstrator().isAvailable(block) ) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
...
    
    public Demonstrator getDemonstrator() {
        return (Demonstrator) super.getVariable();
    }
}
```

```
public class Period {
    
    private String name;
    private LocalDateTime start;
    // duration in seconds
    private int duration;
    private Lecturer lecturer;
    private ArrayList<Demonstrator> dems;
    private ArrayList<Skill> skills;
    
    /**
     * Basic constructor. Use the factory method from() to make a period from AvailBlock objects.
     * @param name
     * @param start
     * @param duration
     * @param lecturer
     */
    public Period(String name, LocalDateTime start, int duration, Lecturer lecturer) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lecturer = lecturer;
        this.dems = new ArrayList<>();
        this.skills = new ArrayList<>();
        this.duration = duration;
        this.start = start;
    }
    
    /**
     * Static factory method that can create a period from a list of consecutive AvailBlock objects.
     * @param name
     * @param blocks
     * @param lecturer
     * @return
     */
    public static Period from(String name, List<AvailBlock> blocks, Lecturer lecturer)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        
        if ( !AvailBlock.isConsecutive(blocks) ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Non-consecutive AvailBlock objects." );
        }
        
        ArrayList<AvailBlock> blocksSorted = new ArrayList<>(blocks);
        Collections.sort(blocksSorted);
        LocalDateTime start = blocksSorted.get(0).getStart();
        int duration = blocksSorted.size();
        
        return new Period(name, start, duration, lecturer);
    }
    
...    
    public LocalDateTime getStart() {
        return start;
    
// more getters and setters ...
    
    public LocalDateTime getEnd() {
        return this.start.plusSeconds(this.duration);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you've imported your own `Period` class? Because there's a `java.time.Period` as well, which doesn't have those methods

Comment: Please provide a sample project.

Comment: Thanks @QBrute - I changed this to ```Lab``` but the problem persists. It also affects ```Demonstrator```. @Andrey, do you mean the whole project? There are a lot of classes there, and they don't all have this problem - can you clarify what else you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all sorts of attempts at invalidating the cache, changing the JDK etc., I have deleted the `<Demonstrator, Period>` part in the `DemAvailConstraint` class declaration. I think I know why this worked. Adding that piece of code made `Demonstrator` and `Period` into placeholder types rather than referring to my custom classes. This is why the class couldn't access my methods. I have kept the placeholder code `<V, D>` (variable and domain) in the abstract class `Constraint`, and I'm now wondering if I actually need to specify those types in the subclass.